# How to get an element by nested value MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

In the document, I write a category object in which there is a field with a category name, cost and date. I need to take certain categories for the year "2022". How can I do this? Right now in my code the console displays "[]" and I need to display the category names where the year is 2022.  Now I have added three objects, two of which have the year 2022. I need to display them in the console. The whole object with the user looks like this in the console: name: 'Tom', 'categories': [ [Array], [Array], [Array] ].

```js
const col = db.collection("users");
col.findOneAndUpdate({
      name: "Tom",
    }, {
      $addToSet: {
        сategories: [{
          name: "products",
          cost: "100$",
          date: {
            day: `13`,
            month: `08`,
            year: `2022`,
          },
        }, ],
      },

      // search 

      collection
      .find({
        year: `2022`,
      })
      .toArray(function(err, results) {
        console.log(results);
        client.close();
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello there Rick and welcome. Although i haven't used Mongo in a while, based on your question, this seems to be an array accessing issue. If you are getting a console log result of "'Tom', 'categories': [ [Array], [Array], [Array] ] "

then traverse it with something like this? Ive given two examples below for you to try.

```
    const col = [ ["david", "lopan"], ["McDonalds", "BurgerKing"] ];
    console.log(col[0][0]); //this outputs "David"
console.log(col[1][0]); //this outputs "McDonalds"
```

etc.

or try

```
const dataset2 = [ {name1: "david", lastname1:"lopan"}, {food:"McDonalds", food2:"BurgerKing"}];

console.log(dataset2[0].name1); // this outputs "David"
```

Essentially, you need to traverse your array and target the type of data in it but you have to go a few levels deep. you are almost there

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I need that when passing a parameter to find (), the result contains the necessary objects, and not the entire object of the user "Tom". So that I don’t have to go through the result using map () and get the necessary data. It's not very optimized